# Finding whether an interval contains at least one integer without math.h

Tags: c

For a class project I need to split some audio clips in smaller sections, for which we are provided a min length and a max length, to figure out whether this is possible, I do the following:

```
a = length/max
b = length/min
```

mathematically I figured that [a,b] contains at least one integer if  `⌊b⌋ >= ⌈a⌉`, but I can't use math.h for floor() and ceil(). Since a and b are always positive I can use type casting for floor(), but I am at a loss at how to do ceil(). I thought about using ((int)x)+1 but that would round integers up which would break the formula.

I would like either a way to do ceil() which would solve my problem, or another way to check whether an interval contains at least one integer.

Comment: Why can't you just cast `a` and `b` into integers and `if(a != b)` then there is at least one integer in the interval.

Comment: Why can't you use `<math.h>`?

Comment: @RoiHatam [2;2.5] contains 2 and your answer doesn't account for that, I guess I could add handling for that special case though I have solved my problem with an answer further down this thread. Can't use math.h because it requires an additional compilation flag which will not be used by the professor when compiling our code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `math.h` to perform floor. Please look at the following code:

```
 int length=5,min=2,max=3; // only an example of inputs.

 int a = length/max;
 int b = length/min;

 if(a!=b){
     //there is at least one integer in the interval.
 }else{
     if(length % min==0 || length % max==0 ){
        //there is at least one integer in the interval.
     }else{
        //there is no integer in the interval.
     }
 }
```

The result for the above example will be that there is an integer in the interval.

You can also perform ceil without using `math.h` as following:

```
int a;
if(length % max == 0){
     a = length / max;
}else{
     a = (length / max) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Your first edit will fail when OP's `a = 2.0` and `b = 2.1`. The integer divisions will be `2` and `2` but there *is* an integer in the range, satisfying `⌊b⌋ >= ⌈a⌉`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question right, I guess, you can do ceil(a) in this case, and then check if the result is less then b. Thus, for example, for interval [1.3, 3.5], ceil(1.3) will return 2, which fits into this interval.

**UPD**
Also you could do (b - a). If it's > 1, there's for sure at least one integer between them.

Comment: Please note "without math.h" in the question title.

Comment: He also said 
"I would like either a way to do ceil() which would solve my problem"

Comment: Not my DV but I am tempted after you deny your error. He also says that he found a way to do `floor()` without using `floor()`. He now wants to find a way to do `ceil()` without using `ceil()`. Please read the question properly.

Comment: Although I said I could not use ceil() and as @WeatherVane pointed out I was looking for a workaround, reversing your method (i.e. if(a<=floor(b)) would work, since I can use typecasting to int as a workaround for floor().

Concerning your updates it's insufficient and relatively trivial but misses all intervals smaller than 1 that contain an integer (e.g. [1.92;2.13]) which in my application I expect to be most. Thank you nonetheless, I shall be using this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general trick in programming that will come in hand if you ever find yourself programming Apple Basic, or any other language where floating point math is supported.

You can "round" a number by addition, then truncation, as follows:

```
x = some floating value
rounded_x = int(x + roundoff_amount)
```

Where `roundoff_amount` is the difference between the lowest fraction to round up, and 1.

So, to round at .5, your round_off would be 1 - .5 = .5, and you would do `int(x + .5)`. If x is .5 or .51 then the result becomes 1.0 or 1.01 and `int()` takes that to 1. Obviously, if x is higher, then you still get rounded to 1, until x becomes 1.5 when rounding takes it to 2. To round upwards starting at .6, your roundoff amount would be 1 - .6 = .4, and you would do `int(x + .4)`, etc.

You can do a similar thing to get `ceil` behavior. Set your roundoff_amount to be 0.99999... and do the round. You can choose your value to provide a "nearby" window, since floats have some inaccuracy inherent that might prevent getting a perfectly integer value after adding fractions.

Comment: You can provide the ability to handle negative as well `int n = (int)( x ? x > 0 ? x + 0.5 : x - 0.5 : 0);`, but note, in either case not all corner cases are handled, e.g. `NAN`, `INF`, `x > INT_MAX`, etc..

Comment: As specified in my original question I am dealing with unsigned ints here, but relevant comment nonetheless, thank you.

Though for my application it doesn't matter, since floating point operations use rounding, I'm guessing using a cutoff too close to 1 would start resulting in rounding up one too much for large numbers correct?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by large numbers. At some point, floats are going to be too big for +1 to mean anything. For your example, where times are likely in minutes or seconds, this shouldn't apply.